# How to add style to first element of ul?

Tags: css, angular, angular6

I am appending an list to top of the array that I display in HTML using li. Now I am trying to add css to first child of li. I have tried the following code.

```
.ts

this.skills.push({title: 'Play button clicked'});
```

.html

```
    <div class="column" class="steps">
        <h2>Steps:</h2>
        <ul *ngFor = "let post of skills" >
            <li>{{ post.title}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>



.css

.steps li:first-child { 
    background-color: yellow;
}
.steps li:not(::first-line) {
}
```

My problem is this css is added to all the li added. I dont want to show different css to li excluding first one.

Comment: You can add a div(of course, only if it's okay for your app) for the first li tag alone and give it an ID and then use styling

Comment: Try this .steps ul >  li { background-color: yellow; }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current selector (`.steps li:first-child`) is perfectly fine; the problem is that you have **two** `class` attributes on your `<div>` element (`<div class="column" class="steps">`), which is invalid HTML. Combining the two into one attribute fixes the problem, as can be seen in the following:

```css
.steps li:first-child {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="column steps">
  <h2>Steps:</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

If you want to have multiple `<ul>` elements, but only want the first child of the first `<ul>` element to be highlighted, you'll want `.steps ul:first-of-type li:first-child`:

```css
.steps ul:first-of-type li:first-child {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="column steps">
  <h2>Steps:</h2>
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes this works fine but when I append more item on button click. The css is taking in all of the li

Comment: So you only want the first `<li>` of the very **first** `<ul>` element to be highlighted?

Comment: Yes @Obsidian Age

Answer (score 1):

**Pure Angular way**

HTML

```
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let item of array(9); let i = index" [class.firstElem]='i==0'></li>
</ul>
```

TS

```
  array(n) {
    return Array(n);
  }
```

CSS

```
.firstElem {
  color : red;
}
```

Working example in [stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3ya9ma)

Comment: You can use first too, see https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables < *ngFor="let item of array(9);let first=first" [class.firstEleme]="first">

Comment: Right. In this case first is more useful @Eliseo
I used index just to generalize the solution. Eg to find odd/even elements etc.

Comment: You have odd and even too :).